# HTML5 Canvas simulate rotation planet around its axis?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have a question about planet rotation simulation in Javascript HTML5 Canvas.

I have canvas object and i need render a circle with spherize and display texture of the planet: for example this http://www.planetaryvisions.com/images_new/4128.jpg

I need rotate that texture and display simulation rotation planet around its axis on canvas (pseudo 3D on 2D Canvas). Rotation in one direction only: just scroll texture.

So, i want do it more realistically than in example implemented in CSS3 ( http://codepen.io/chinchang/pen/xCkus )

Can you provide me a ready solution with example for implementing my task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it...

Demo (non-animated version):  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/tsEL8/

[image]

Create a circular clipping region (context.arc + context.clip) to be your globe.

Use drawImage to draw your 4128.jpg into the clip so the left side of the image is at the left side of your clipping region.

Give your globe a 3D illusion by drawing slight inset shadows on the left and right sides of your clipping region.  This will make the image appear to have depth as it "wraps" around the left and right side of the globe.

You can create the inset shadow by drawing a quarter-circle arcs on both the left and right side of the clipping region and using shadowOffsetX to extend the shadow rightward on the left side of the globe and extend leftward on the right side of the globe.

During each animation loop

- Clear the canvas
- drawImage your 4128.jpg with its "x" position shifted 1 additional pixel leftward.
- Draw the inset shadow.

When you have moved 4128.jpg as far leftward as it can go without exposing empty space, draw another copy of 4128.jpg at the right side of the first 4128.jpg (creating an endless loop of 4128's).

Here's code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var img4128=new Image();
    img4128.onload=function(){
        start();
    }
    img4128.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/4128.jpg";

    function start(){

        // clip a circle representing a globe

        ctx.arc(100,100,50,0,Math.PI*2,false);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.clip();


        // drawImage the map into the clip

        ctx.globalAlpha=.50;
        ctx.drawImage(img4128,-20,0);
        ctx.globalAlpha=1.00;

        // draw shadows on left and right side of globe

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(100,100,52,Math.PI*0.70,Math.PI*1.30,false);
        ctx.shadowColor="black";
        ctx.shadowBlur=5;
        ctx.shadowOffsetX=5;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(100,100,52,-Math.PI*0.30,Math.PI*0.30,false);
        ctx.shadowColor="black";
        ctx.shadowBlur=5;
        ctx.shadowOffsetX=-5;
        ctx.stroke();

    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide simple abstract example without animation?

Comment: Hey, i need a few that object on one canvas. Can you help me how to make that? I'm trying manipulating with your code but not understand how to create a few objects on canvas.

Comment: Just put the drawing code in a function.  Be sure you enclose the draw commands with context.save/context.restore.  Here's and example:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/upLcc/1/ Good luck with your project!

Comment: @markE sorry to comment on an old answer, but i find having the texture move to simulate rotation a bit tricky =/ i don't know how it would be done.